# How to optimize NLTK Naive Bayes for large training data

Tags: python, performance, migration, bigdata, nltk

On training the NLTK Naive Bayes algorithm for 6 million word samples each with 25 feature set training samples. 
I get following error in `/var/syslog`:

> Out of memory: Kill process 31349 (python) score 787 or sacrifice child

The system has 32gb RAM, 7 cores and after 3 days of running I get the above message.

What can I do to optimize the NLTK Naive Bayes in order to handle this error? Should I just migrate to other platforms like **scikit**, **datao**?

Comment: NLTK naive bayes isn't optimized for speed or memory. Use `scikit-learn` instead.

Comment: what about datao @alvas

Comment: You don't give any information that could be used to answer your question, but I'm guessing you need to design your feature function with fewer features. If you ran out of memory out of three days, you are probably creating new features ad infinitum... features are no use unless they occur often.